# Sorting Algorithms with Doubly-Linked-Lists

Tags: doubly-linked-list, sorting

I have to implement four sorting algorithms(Insertion, Selection, Shell, Quicksort) with doubly linked list as a homework, but I'm completely lost because all the explanations of those sorting algorithms I found online require the use of arrays. I tried to use this code as a pseudo index for my DLL:

```
public DoubleNode this[int num]
    {
        get
        {
            DoubleNode x = head;
            for(int k = 0; k < num; k++)
                x = x.Next;

            return x;
        }
    }
```

But it's not enough, cause it's not a setter. Any ideas guys/girls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to sort a double linked list in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614162/what-is-the-best-way-to-sort-a-double-linked-list-in-c)

Comment: You're going on the wrong direction - you do not want to emulate an array. What you want to do is first understand the algorithms and how they apply to lists differently.

Comment: @Ofir: the thing is, most of them *don't* apply to linked lists in any practical way.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt That's exactly the issue I'm having. The only one that is easily implemented is Merge Sort. I guess I'll have to put all the info in an array, sort it, then put it back in the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK (based on my comment) one example is insert - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#List_insertion_sort_code_in_C.2B.2B - insert sort is actually a bit more suitable to list than to arrays (because the insert operation in an array means moving elements).

The same goes to quicksort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Simple_version

Selection sort is trivial to implement over a list - you use two pointers, one (I'll call that the head) pointing to the next unsorted position (starting from the start of the list and moving one step ahead each time) and the other searching for a minimal element from the head to the end of the list.

Shell sort is based on insertion sort, and shouldn't be too hard to implement based on that idea.

Comment: Thank you all for helping. I finished my homework yesterday. In a way I feel like I'm obligated to post the code so there is an actual example of sorting algorithms with lists online lol.